# Rails Action Cable with Postgresql adapter on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, redis, actioncable

I'm making a new web app (Rails 6) that I would like to use websockets with. This is the first time I've attempted to use ActionCable with Rails. Ideally to start I would toss the app up on Heroku, since it is generally a fast and convenient way for me to get started with an app project.

If my app is successful I wouldn't be surprised if it had 200 concurrent users. This doesn't seem like a lot to me. I assume many of them would have open other tabs, so my estimate would be roughly 500 websocket connections for 200 users. If my site were more successful, I could see this going to 500 active users so more than 1000 websocket connections.

After preliminary research, it is recommended to use Redis on Heroku for ActionCable. I was dismayed to see that a Redis plan (Redistogo) with 500 websocket connections would cost $75/month and 1000 connections $200/month. More than dismayed, really. Shocked. Am I missing something? Why is this so expensive? It seems like these plans are also linked to large amounts of storage space, something that (my understanding) ActionCable doesn't even need.

I've seen that it's also possible (in theory) to configure ActionCable to use Postgresql as its adapter, though looking online I didn't see any examples of anyone doing this successfully on Heroku. So my questions are these:

1. Is it possible to use ActionCable on Heroku without paying through the nose? I assume this would mean Postgresql adapter...
2. How many connections could such a setup handle, what are the limitations, bottlenecks, etc?
3. I wasn't able to find much information about ActionCable and Postgresql, except that the number of `pools` has to match. I assume the `pool` number is not the same as the websocket connection count?

Thanks for any info...